# Parameters in the additional jquery to hash id

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jquery hash apparently works perfectly when you sent the link with its own ID.

The problem arises if you add additional parámentros eg url.com/#menu-1&utm=menu, this fails, but if I put the id only if it works url.com/#menu-1

There would be a possible solution?

**WORKS:**

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-1
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-2
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-3
```

**It Does Not Work:**

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-1&utm=menu-1
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-2&utm=menu-2
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/#menu-3&utm=menu-3
```

EXAMPLE JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ecp15eks/1/

**JS:**

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash != "") {
    $('.tabs-menu li a[href="' + hash + '"]').trigger("click");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li><a href="#menu-1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-2">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#menu-3">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="menu-1" class="tab-content">
         <h1>Menu Content 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-2" class="tab-content">
         <h1>Menu Content 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-3" class="tab-content">
         <h1>Menu Content 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing URL parameters with named anchors.

Your named anchor is `#menu-1`--you haven't actually created a URL Parameter yet.

You should be using:

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/?utm=menu-1#menu-1
```

Note that named anchors should be final piece of the URL, and the URL parameters need to come before it.

In the code above I have appended the URL Parameter `utm=menu-1`.

You then could append additional parameters at the end with your ampersand. E.g.:

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/1/show/light/?utm=menu-1&utn=menu-2#menu-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
hash = hash.split(/\?|&/);
//Checks for '? or &' on hash and splits there

if (hash[0] != "") {
    //hash[0] == first value of hash array 
    $('.tabs-menu li a[href="' + hash[0] + '"]').trigger("click");
}
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ecp15eks/10/)